# Pass integer to child process

Tags: c, linux

I have a parent process that reads output from a child process and writes input to the child process where required. The child process reaches a line of java code (not my code and cannot alter) that takes an integer as input. I cannot get the write() call to send an integer and newline (to simulate pressing ). I have tried the many suggestions found in other threads to no avail. Is there a way?

```
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "1\n", 2); //Log file says ^@1 entered

int choice = 1;
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &choice, 1);
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "\n", 1); //Loops back around as if I just pushed enter

char choice = 1;
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &choice, 1);
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "\n", 1); //Loops back around as if I just pushed enter

char choice[2] = {0x31, 0x0D}; // 1 and CR
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &choice, 2); //Incorrect choice:726

char choice = "\001";
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &choice, 1);
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "\n", 1); //Forget the outcome, but didn't work
```

Java code to parse the input:

```
String[] enteredChoice = enteredChoiceStr.split(",");
for ( String indexStr : enteredChoice ) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(indexStr);
    if ( index == 0 || index > totalNum ) {
        isError = true;
        ErrorMsg="Invalid number entered: "+indexStr+". Verify the number.";
        cu.wprintln("");
        cu.wprintln(ErrorMsg);
```

Comment: What does the reading side of the code look like?

Comment: It depends an exactly how the Java process is expecting the the number.  Is it looking for a serialized int or the textual representation of the int?

Comment: This code is fine (for sending binary data -- why then a newline?), but you must be aware that the data will arrive in the parent on the read end of the pipe connecting the parent and child, not on the parent `stdin`.  You may also have buffering issues... `write` has less buffering than `stdio.h` functions such as `fwrite`, but it may be worth adding a flush.

Comment: I need to (at least I have figured out how I do not need to) pass in a newline to simulate pressing 'Enter' Not sure why that didn't show up in the post :/

Comment: Code to parse the input. I assume sending the newline (\n) is the problem. How can I write '1' and "press enter"?
`String[] enteredChoice = enteredChoiceStr.split(",");
                    for ( String indexStr : enteredChoice ) {
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(indexStr);
                        if ( index == 0 || index > totalNum ) {
                            isError = true;
                            ErrorMsg="Invalid number entered: "+indexStr+".  Verify the number.";
                            cu.wprintln("");
                            cu.wprintln(ErrorMsg);`

Comment: Minor: Not sure why code is `char choice[2] = {0x31, 0x0D}; // 1 and CR` rather than `char choice[2] = {'1', '\r'};`.  What advantage to the original style?

Comment: How is the java code reading in enteredChoiceStr from the pipe?

Comment: @Ben Voigt "This code is fine"   Hmmm, should not `char choice = "\001";` be `char choice = '\001';`?

Comment: So you are parsing text data, so you cannot send binary data, as you do in several of the code snippets.

Comment: So the disadvantage here is that the posted attempts did not include previous commands. There was a previous `write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "\n", 2);` The length was 1 too long so I assume that whatever garbage was there was buffered which is why the log showed my input as "^@1" I corrected the length, and all seems well now. Thanks for your assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have few minor errors in your code. This is the correct version:

```
...
int choice = 1;
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &choice, sizeof(int)); // you are sending binary data here, probably not what you want 
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "\n", 1);
...

char choice[2] = {0x31, 0x0D};
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, choice, 2); // choice is an array, that decays into a pointer

char choice = '\001';
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &choice, 1); // \001 is not '1', you are effectively writing binary data here
write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "\n", 1);
```

Do note that the reading side must match the writing side. If you are writing binary data, you need to read binary data in the same format. If you are writing textual data, you need to parse them as text.

Comment: @chux Thanks missed that one.

Comment: I _think_ OP is really interested in sending text though.